# Chart.js align line graph to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

i am wondering why my chart isn't aligned to the left and how i can do this? This is my code:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["ID"]
    , datasets: [
        {
            label: "Sensor 1"
            , data: [{
                x: 0
                , y: 2
            }, {
                x: 12
                , y: 5
            }]
            , backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            , ]
            , borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ]
            , borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]
};
var options = {
    title: {
        display: true
        , text: 'Custom Chart Title'
    }
    , scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
        , xAxes: [{
            type: "linear"
            , position: "bottom"
        }]
    }
};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(ctx, {
    data: data
    , options: options
});
```

The line starts right in the center of the graph but i don't know how i can align it to the left  (on the x-Axis). This is how it looks like:

https://picload.org/image/raoipwci/chartjs.png

As you can see, another problem is, that the y-axis doesn't match up with the dataset i entered.

Edit: Okay, i finally got it working. I added the correct code.

Comment: are you able to produce a snippet or a fiddle which reproduces the issue

Comment: i added the complete code and an image

Comment: @binaryBigInt it's a lot more helpful to others running into the same issue if you post an answer rather than editing the question. That way you can more easily see what the problem was and find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but i think I have the solution for your problem and I'll leave it here for somebody else who is searching this (I can't test it right now but should be this):

```
xAxes: [{
        type: "linear"
        , position: "bottom"
        , beginAtZero: true
        , min: 0
}]
```

Somebody let me know if it's right :)

Comment: I don't think this is right...Those attributes should be out in the ticks object

Answer (score 0):

```
            padding: {
                      top: 50,
                      right: 10,
                      bottom: 50,
                      left: 10,
                     }
            }

Add this object in your graph options and change the position with top, bottom, left, right
```